# How does $(Ax -b)^T(Ax -b)$ reduce to $x^TA^TAx − 2b^TAx + b^Tb$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am not sure if I can write $(Ax -b)^T$ as $(A^Tx^T -b^T)$. If I can, I can't reproduce the above result. Please help. Also refer to any sources that will give me a good insight in matrix derivatives.

Comment: No, $(Ax -b)^T=(x^TA^T -b^T)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ (A x - b)^T (A x - b) $$ $$ = \left[(A x)^T - b^T \right] (A x - b) $$
$$ = ( x^T A^T - b^T ) (A x - b) $$
$$ = x^T A^T (A x - b) - b^T (A x - b)$$
$$ = x^T A^T A x - x^T A^T b - b^T A x + b^T b $$
$$ = x^T A^T A x - (b^T A x)^T - b^T A x + b^T b $$

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, $b^T A x$ is a dot product of two vectors $b$ and $A x$, which is a scalar. Therefore $(b^T A x)^T = b^T A x$ and $$ (A x - b)^T (A x - b) = x^T A^T A x - 2 b^T A x + b^T b \mathrm{.} $$

Comment: @JeanMarie As pointed out by Rodrigo de Azevedo the matrix $A$ doesn't need to be symmetrical as $b^T A x$ is a scalar.

Comment: @655321 I assumed symmetry, which was a mistake.

Comment: The matrix $A$ does not have to be symmetrical, the result holds even for non square matrices

Answer (score 3):

$$\|Ax-b\|^2=\left(Ax-b\right)^T\left(Ax-b\right)=\left(\left(Ax\right)^T-b^T\right)\left(Ax-b\right)=\left(x^TA^T-b^T\right)\left(Ax-b\right)=x^TA^TAx-b^TAx-x^TA^Tb+b^Tb$$
if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ therefore:

$b^TAx = \sum\limits_{i=1}^mb_i(Ax)_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\sum\limits_{j=1}^n b_i(a_{ij}x_j)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \sum\limits_{i=1}^m x_j(a_{ij}b_i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n  x_j(A^Tb)_j= x^TA^Tb$

So, eventually:
$$\left(Ax-b\right)^T\left(Ax-b\right)=x^TA^TAx-2b^TAx+b^Tb$$